# Rest request using Inheritance in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to call a REST service and I am doing something like this.
A base class for all HTTP requests:

```
 import { Injector }    from '@angular/core';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
    export class HttpRoot {
      public url:string;
      public type:string;
      protected http:Http;
      constructor(public injector:Injector){
        this.http = injector.get(Http);
      };
      callAPI(){
        return this.http.get(this.url).map((resCont:Response) => {
          console.log(resCont);
          return resCont;
        }).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
      }
      successHandler(res:any){
        console.log('there');
      }
      failureHandler(res:any){

      }
    }
```

Child class that extends HttpRoot

```
import { HttpRoot }    from './HttpRoot';
import { Injector }    from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
export class HttpGet extends HttpRoot {
  constructor(public injector:Injector,public url:string){
    super(injector);
    this.type="GET";
  };
}
```

And finally service

```
import { Injectable,Injector }    from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpGet } from './API/HttpGet';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
@Injectable()
export class CommentsService {

  commentsUrl:string="../data/data.json";
  constructor(private http:Http,private injector:Injector){

  };
  comments:any[];
  private getRequest:HttpGet;
  //
  getComments(){
    this.getRequest=new HttpGet(this.injector,this.commentsUrl);
    var returnRES = this.getRequest.callAPI();

  }
}
```

I am injecting this service this service to my component and calling the getCommnets methods.Using breakpoint I can find that callAPI of HttpRoot is invoking but no ajax request taking placing.
Can someone please help where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP service just make request when we subscribe it.
And this is ajax call so, data or any action use result of this service should be put inside subscribe function.

```
getComments(){
    this.getRequest=new HttpGet(this.injector,this.commentsUrl);
    this.getRequest.callAPI().subscribe(data => {
         var returnRES = data;
    });

  }
```